# Custom Softmax Function on Keras

Tags: python, keras, one-hot-encoding, softmax, activation-function

I need to custom Softmax function to directly to be one_hot encoding form, However, I gained en error.

e.g. the output of an original-softmax function is [0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1].

I want to force the output to be [1, 0, 0, 0]

Note: My model is LSTM with a many-to-many model with a batch mechanism.

**Current error**: `ValueError: Tried to convert 'x' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.`

```py
def mysoftmax(x, axis=-1):
    e = K.exp(x - K.max(x, axis=axis, keepdims=True))
    s = K.sum(e, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
    a = e/s
    z = K.one_hot(K.argmax(a, axis=axis), 4)
    return z
```